# How to scale up picture in Python?

Tags: python, image, scale

I am really do not know how to scale up a part of picture. I need scale up someone's nose.

Example:

```
def scaleUp():
    pic=makePicture(pickAFile())
    width=getWidth()
    height=getHeight()
```

Comment: Python [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) maybe what you're looking for as an image editing library

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html) library to do that:

```
import Image

infile = "test.png"
outfile = "test_resized.jpg"
size = (1024, 768)

im = Image.open(infile)
print im.size   # Size in pixels

# Resize:
im.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save(outfile, "JPEG")
```

Comment: I am trying make someone's nose bigger than original picture